# in_array with single and multidimension

Tags: php

I have two arrays a single dimension and multidim array ,the multidimension its comma

separated

```
$singledim =Array
(
    [0] => 333
    [1] => 673
    [2] => 434
    [3] => 67

)

$multidim = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 3336,673,34,342,432,23,323,434,765675765,7657567
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 2424,10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
            [1] => 23,12,13,14,15,16
        )
............
}
```

I want to use in_array to check the single dimension array value exists .Belwo is the one i tried..

```
<?
foreach($multidim  as $multi)
{
  if(in_array($singledim,$multi[1])
  {

  }
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Right now you are checking to see if you entire `$singledim` array match an element in `$multi[1]`. This is never going to match. Can you state in words exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: please provide expected output (with meaningful examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($multidim as $multi){
    foreach($singledim as $single){
        $temp_array = explode(',',$mutli[1]);
        if(in_array($single, $temp_array)){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If you pass an array, that same array group must exist exactly in the same manner in the haystack in order to match.

Comment: I get error like this in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Comment: Since $multi[1] is a string ,its an array ?

Comment: try now, didn't notice it was not an array, you will have to explode it

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `in_array()`. you want `strpos(...) !== false`. and note you WILL be subject to false positives. e.g. if you're searching for `1`, then your `12`, `21`, etc... will false match. Your structure needs to be normalized, and each value individual value in the `[1]` sub-element should be its OWN array element.

Answer (score 0):

`$multi[1]` is not an array. It is a comma separated string.

You can use `explode` to create an array from the string:

```
$vals = explode(',' ,$multi[1]);
if(in_array($singledim, $vals)
{

}
```

However, that will only work if `$singledim` is a string.

As noted in the comments, you are checking if a whole array is the same as the string in the second array. You could convert the first array to a string and then check they are equal:

```
$singleDimStr = implode(',' ,$singledim);
if($singleDimStr == $multi[1]) { 
}
```